# Installation of Azure Machine Learning Workbench fails on Windows 10

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I tried to install the azure machine learning workbench from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/preview/quickstart-installation). Once I double click on the downloaded MSI file, it shows the first screen about licensing terms. Once I click on Continue, it shows dependencies. When I click Install, it starts installation. It downloads Miniconda with Python 3.5.2. While trying to install asn1crypto 0.23.0, it suddenly stops and displays 'Installation fails'. I tried running the MSI file with log option but no error is reported in the log.

Here are my machine details:
Windows 10
Version 1709 (OS Build 17017.1000)

How can I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1):

you can have a look at the installer log (%TEMP%\AmlInstaller\Logs). See if there is any obvious error... What version of windows are you running, is it a preview?